# Pass request headers in a jQuery AJAX GET call

Tags: jquery, ajax, client-side

I am trying to pass request headers in an AJAX GET using jQuery. In the following block, "data" automatically passes the values in the querystring. Is there a way to pass that data in the request header instead ?

```
$.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost/PlatformPortal/Buyers/Account/SignIn",
         data: { signature: authHeader },
         type: "GET",
         success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
      });
```

The following didn't work either

```
$.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost/PlatformPortal/Buyers/Account/SignIn",
         beforeSend: { signature: authHeader },
         async: false,                    
         type: "GET",
                    success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
      });
```

Answer (score 325, accepted):

Use `beforeSend`:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost/PlatformPortal/Buyers/Account/SignIn",
         data: { signature: authHeader },
         type: "GET",
         beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header', 'test-value');},
         success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
      });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method

Comment: i know this is super-old by now.  but I wanted to add that there should be a comma after:

beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header', 'test-value');}

Comment: beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header', 'test-value');} works well in chrome and firefox but not in IE8. there is no X-Test-Header send. how to fix it? Thx

Comment: i have tried but it throw error when i am passing header detail in using "jquery-1.11.1.min.js"

Comment: see below answer, much more relevant

Comment: What if I want to add `X-Test-Header` and `X-Test-Header` to the `beforeSend`?

Comment: is this possible with "jsonp"?

Comment: this response is the correct one if you use jsonp, but if you don't see @Lukas response below.  Warning if you both use https for url AND jsonp it won't work.

Comment: What If i want to pass a json object in 'x-text-header'? I tried it and it receives `[Object Object]`

Answer (score 450):

As of jQuery 1.5, there is a `headers` hash you can pass in as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/test",
    headers: {"X-Test-Header": "test-value"}
});
```

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax:

> **headers** (added 1.5): A map of additional header key/value pairs to send along with the request. This setting is set before the beforeSend function is called; therefore, any values in the headers setting can be overwritten from within the beforeSend function.

Comment: Yes: `$.ajaxSetup({headers: {"X-Test-Header": "test-value"}})`

Comment: The jQuery docs don't recommend using $.ajaxSetup() anymore (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Comment: @Glen Their reasoning is that plugins might be expecting default settings to work. Personally, I think it's a given that if you globally change something, something that was depending on the default settings might not work.

Comment: @Trip My recommendation for globally... write your own wrapper for ajax calls (abstraction) instead of calling $.ajax().

Comment: be aware this doesn't work with jsonp (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433556/jquery-jsonp-ajax-authentication-header-not-being-set) for jsonp refere to @Adam response

Comment: Be aware, if you send cross-domain request you must allow your custom header in .httaccess with `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, ..., x-test-header"`, otherwise an error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://...' from origin 'http://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field X-Test-Header is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: What If i want to pass a json object in 'x-text-header'? I tried it and it receives `[Object Object]` when I do so

Comment: @Rishav JSON objects are not allowed in headers. You'll have to JSON.stringify it and then parse it on the server.

Comment: If you really want to use JSON in a header, I recommend you to JSON.stringify and Base64 encode it. Special characters could cause issues in proxies between the browser and the backend.

Answer (score 57):

```js
$.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'header1': 'value1',
                'header2': 'value2'
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
               // CallBack(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                
            }
        });
```

Comment: Using jQuery 1.7.2, C# API 2.x, when trying to extract from header `HttpRequestMessage r = new HttpRequestMessage(); int mylogonID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Headers.GetValues("logonID"));` error out because **The given header was not found.** because r.Headers is empty.

Comment: you may want to try something like -
string[] ids = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["logonID"].Split(',');

Comment: dataType should be written ad datatype