# How to add Custom header In html page in ajax request

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have to send my password using ***ajax request*** in html page to ***wcf webservice*** and then in wcf service i want to retrive my password in following format so what can i do to set header in html page.

```
Password = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Password"].ToString()
```

I use following code but it is not get password in  server side means in webservice in above format.

```
function setHeader(xhr) 
{
     xhr.setRequestHeader('UserName', document.getElementById('textinput1').value);
}
```

Comment: xhr.setRequestHeader('Password', document.getElementById('textinput1')

Comment: Can you show your whole JS code where you set headers for AJAX request? `setHeader` looks to be ok,but there may be an issue with how you are using it.

Comment: Try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call

Comment: @Dev Where do you see at least a sign of jQuery here?

Comment: @FAngel Read that post fully man, there is a link given below with reference to jquery site. Given 11 up votes to that answer.

Comment: success: function (response) {
                   
                    if (response == ("success").toLocaleLowerCase()) {

                        alert("Loging Successfully!!..");
                        window.location = "patient_list.html";
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Please Loging Again!!..");

                    }

                },
                error: function (error) {

                    alert("ERROR:", error);

                },
                beforeSend: setHeader,

Comment: @Suhas code in comments is hard to read. You should place it in you question by editing it.