# pass header value in jQuery AJAX POST firefox

Tags: c#, jquery, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I called a Rest service in jQuery AJAX POST method. I need to pass two values in header.
Firefox neither pass the header value to the service nor calls the REST service. 
My Jquery code

```
var postCall = function () {
    $.support.cors = true;
    var HFAssoRefId = document.getElementById('MainContent_HFAssoRefId').value;      
    var Input = {
        AssoRefId: HFAssoRefId
    };   
    alert(JSON.stringify(Input));
    var url = document.URL;
    var name = "samuel";        
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("PartnerName", name);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("URL", url);
        },
        url: "http://localhost:40680/Service.svc/TokenInsertion",
        data: JSON.stringify(Input),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {              
            alert(status);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any other methods to pass the header values in jQuery AJAX. It works fine with Internet Explorer 8. How to make it work compatible with Firefox browser also ?

I tried the other methods for posting like this. 
Method 1 :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function(){   
        var name1 = "samuel";
        var url1 = document.URL;  
        $.post('http://localhost:41855/IntegrationCheck/Default.aspx', {
            name : name1,
            url  : url1
        },function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

and MEthod 2 in AJAX jQuery:

```
function setHeader() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', '');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml;application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("PartnerName", name);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("URL", url);
}
```

But the header values are not passed and the service is not called in Firefox.
Any suggestions..

Comment: You do have a couple of syntactical errors in your first code snippet, but they ought to make it not work in IE either so I'd assume they are just artifacts from entering the code here

Comment: The comma after `AssoRefId: HFAssoRefId,`
Missing parenthesis to close `$.ajax({` after the closing `}`

Comment: And it wouldn't explain why the other two queries don't work :)

Comment: yes. I have corrected the syntax errors. But its not working in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

I used to follow the below approach to set request header.  Please try it if works for you.

[Script]

```
 $("#element").ajaxSuccess(function (evt, request, settings) {
    $('.Status').html(request.getResponseHeader("Status"));
  });
```

[View]

```
  <h2>Status:</h2><h2 class="Status" style="color:Red;">
```

[Controller]

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Save(Order orders)
    {
        string status = string.Empty;

        if (orders != null)
        {
            OrderRepository.Update(orders);
            status = "Updated";
        }

        Response.AddHeader("Status", status);            
        return data.GridActions<EditableOrder>();
    }
```

[image: Response header]

Comment: Its good. But I need to pass the header values in client side only.

Answer (score 0):

Read about **headers** at [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

[Pass request headers in a jQuery AJAX GET call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call)

Comment: I tried using headers and also using AJAX GET call. The headers are not passed in Firefox.