# CakePHP - Ajax not working correctly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

#Edit I use CakePHP 2.3.5

I would like to know what is the problem with my Ajax request and Controller behaviour.
These are the issues i encounter:

1. Ajax - POST request always fails (i always get ERROR response)
2. Even that, i can add new User to databse O_o
3. Even that i have beforeFilter to recognise ajax request still redirects to view
   (as you can see in the source below i have added autoRender paramter false)

I don't really know what is going up, i will be grateful for any kind of help!

Here's the source code:

My ajax request

```
$('.addUser').on('click', function(){
    var data = $('#UserAddForm').serialize();      
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        evalScripts: true,
        url: 'Users/add',
        data: data,
        success: function (){
            $('#regInfo').html("User was created");
            $('#regInfo').css('color', 'darkgreen');

        },
        error: function(){
            $('#regInfo').html("User was not created");
            $('#regInfo').css('color', 'darkgreen');
        }
    });
})
```

My UserController in CakePHP

```
public function add() {

if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->User->create();
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

}

And in my AppController

```
public function beforeFilter(){  
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
         Configure::write('debug', 0);
         $this->autoRender = false;
         $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to dirtily test for ajax in your controller? What I usually do is something like `if($this->data['mobile']){ echo "foo bar"; exit 0;}`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't do the trick :(

Comment: Are you adding the `mobile` parameter in your ajax post with some valid data to pass the `if`? Try to remove your logic in `beforeFilter` to let the controller handle everything

Comment: Also are you using the Security component?

Comment: Yes, i do.
<some chars>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do here for debugging:

1 -- First, make sure that your requests are reaching the right controller function. I notice you have `url: 'Users/add',` in your ajax function. Generally, that would be `url: '/Users/add',` or find another way to get the base path before you call the controller/view

You can do simple tests to make sure it's reaching the controller view function:

```
$('.addUser').on('click', function(){
    var data = $('#UserAddForm').serialize();      
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        evalScripts: true,
        url: 'Users/add',
        data: data,
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
})

public function add() {
   $this->layout = 'ajax';
   $this->autoRender = false;
   echo json_encode(array('this is some' => ' json data'));
}
```

2 -- If #1 works fine then, start double checking your posted data:

```
   public function add() {    
        $this->layout = 'ajax';    
        $this->autoRender = false;
        //just checking for request data because you 
        //may be doing a put and not knowing it    
        if ($this->request->data) {        
            echo json_encode($this->request->data);    
        } 
    }
```

use chrome or firefox and check the output.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer! I'll check Your solution right away! :)

Comment: The request is reaching the controller. On the second step data is displayed on the view.

I decided to add `$this->request->is('ajax')`    
and my controller doesn't see my ajax request. Returns false.

Comment: `if($this->request->is('ajax'){ //rest of the code }` 
returns false

Comment: try setting the header manually in your request. Cake might not recognize the default header. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ -- example :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call