# Ajax post failed with error OPTIONS

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to send out the pwd & username to server to verify, using a POST method. I'm currently running on localhost

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax('/auth/', {
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("post success!");
        },
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username+":"+pwd_SHA1)},
        error: function(jq, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("post error");
        }
    });
```

The following are printed on the console:

```
OPTIONS /auth/
post error
```

With the call stack printed.

The server did not receive the request at all， thus errorThrown is empty string.

What is wrong here?

Comment: it is hard to figure out the problem with only this much amount of info. try using a tool like fiddler to diagnose the exact problem. or check wether you are receiving the request server side and what error status code the server is returning

Comment: Start by logging `errorThrown`.

Comment: I checked. The server did not receive the request at all

Comment: @OskarHane errorThrown is empty string because the server never received the request

Comment: @CharlesW. have you tried `beforeSend` instead to add your header? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call

Comment: @OskarHane hmmm... just tried to set the header in beforeSend. didn't work

Comment: Why don’t you pass `username` and `password` in the `settings` parameter as described in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out why...

In my apache site setting I have AllowOverride none. Therefore the .htaccess file is getting ignored. Thus the request can't be directed to the correct .php file.

Sorry I couldn't provide relevant info in my original question. Thanks for helping