# ckeditor : set header while uploading an image

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, fckeditor, ckfinder

I am using CKeditor 4. In that `Image` plugin.

I have removed unwanted tabs on Image popup and also set the `config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl` to my server's URL.

Now I have to upload the image, I am able to select the image, then when I click on `Send it to server` button, AJAX call goes to my server, But my server requires a particular header set for authentication.

Question is - can I set the header before sending that request ?

Comment: Do you want to show the header in browser? If you want to see the header then you can see it in Firebug panel in net Tab.

Comment: I want to set AJAX request header while uploading the file.

Comment: Ajax request Header??? In my knowledge there is not any ajax header exists. Do you want to upload the file asynchronously?

Comment: There are `Request Headers` we can set in key value format while making the request.

Comment: Possibly you can find some help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call

Comment: Yeah, that is understood but where should I place that code ? I am unable to find callback of `send to server` button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default upload tab of CKEditor doesn't use any AJAX call to upload files. It's just an iframe with a normal form and file input, so you can't change the request headers.

If you want to upload files with an AJAX call then you must write your own code or use the [SimpleUploads plugin](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/p/simpleuploads-plugin-for-ckeditor.html), and configure it to your needs. (disclaimer: I'm its author)

Comment: Thanks for the response, understood the thing now. Is there any way(method) that I can put my browse button and submit button on "upload" tab of the iframe generated by Ckeditor ?

Comment: I am going with writing small custom plugin. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes. You can customize the dialogs using the API that they provide. Look at the provided samples, one of them show how to modify the dialogs.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **`CKEditor version 4.9 +`** then there is one way you can do this.

I faced the same problem while working, so after some search and trying some code samples I found the way.

There are some configurations that you have to set,

again I repeat this is for **`CKEditor version 4.9 +`**.

set below configuration in your **ckeditor**  config object

```
{
     filebrowserUploadUrl : 'your upload path goes here',
     filebrowserUploadMethod: 'xhr',             
     fileTools_requestHeaders: {
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'your_custom_header_name': 'custom_header_value' 
     }
}
```

I will attach a reference here

[fileTools_requestHeaders](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-fileTools_requestHeaders)

[filebrowserUploadMethod](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-filebrowserUploadMethod)

In the code sample above,

**`filebrowserUploadUrl`**: is the api-url that ckeditor will call while uploading

when uploaded ckeditor **emits** **`fileUploadRequest`** event,

you can **change/set** headers after catching that event too.

**`filebrowserUploadMethod`**: when set to 'xhr', it allows you to set the extra headers, by default value will be 'xhr' only.