# request.xhr CORS Layout Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain, cors

If I send a `remote: true` request to our subdomain controller, our layout renders (which it shouldn't)

Having tested the `request.xhr?` method in the action, it's returning `nil` (not the true / false) that you'd expect. This works for non-CORS ajax. It only stops working with CORS-ajax (for subdomain)

---

Here's the code:

```
#app/views/controller/view.html.haml
= link_to "test", new_user_session_url, remote: :true

#routes
new_user_session_path   GET  /login(.:format)    admin/users/sessions#new {:subdomain=>"test"}
```

The response occurs & we get a layout

**We want no layout, which works without CORS**:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
layout :layout_select

  def layout_select
    if request.xhr?
      false
    else
      devise_controller? ? "admin" : "application"
    end
  end
```

We have CORS policy set up & working. However, it seems our CORS-request is not being treated as `xhr`. **Any ideas?**

Comment: This has been brought up on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/95jN3XLKJa4) and a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14425) was thwarted, too. Hopefully you can get all the information you need from those resources.

Comment: Thanks Mike, checking it out now!

Comment: I've found something which works - `headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}` although I think this skips the CORS policy stuff

Comment: looks as though it just adds the header that rails uses to detect xhr requests. If it works for you, you should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In light of the comments from `Mike Campbell`, I was able to determine that [CORS requests are not treated as `ajax` (`xhr`) by default](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14425)

The problem lies in the headers which are passed on an Ajax request. Standard ajax passes the following header:

```
  #actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb
  def xhr?
       @env['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] =~ /XMLHttpRequest/ 
  end
```

This is passed with a "naked" Ajax request, which allows the `xhr?` method to return either true or false. The issue is in a CORS ajax call, this header is not passed. I don't know why, but it just sends an `ORIGIN` header instead

The proposed fix from Github suggested to include this:

```
 uri.host != @env['HTTP_HOST'] || uri.scheme != @env['rack.url_scheme'] || uri.port != @env['HTTP_PORT'].to_i
```

This would basically return a boolean response based on whether the request was from the same domain as the script. Although this was prevented for being unsafe, it lead me to two fixes:

> 1. Append a new `cors?` method to the Rails core
> 2. Send the `http_x_requested_with` header through a CORS request

Considering we are just trying to access a subdomain with the request, we felt that editing the Rails core was slightly overkill, although right. Instead, we found that using the inbuilt [`headers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call) argument in jquery would help:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}});
```

---

Whilst this works, I am eager to hear about any security issues it may present. And plus, whether we can access `json` and other formats with it

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the **Same-Origin Policy**. Please read carefully this article: [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

The possible solutions are:

- make *simple request* – instead of `remote: true` do usual form post or maybe `$.getJSON()` will work (not sure).
- implement *preflight request* – you'll need to implement on your server response for OPTIONS request.
- if you need to maintain cookies then you'll also need to write custom ajax code, eg. `$.ajax({url: a_cross_domain_url, crossDomain: true, xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}});` and return some specific headers from the server.