# Don't reload AJAX when back browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Summary my situation:
I have 2 page:

- page 1 send request $.ajax and get JSON to show. Then in page 1 has a button click --> page 2.

- after I clicked this button, I'm in page 2. I click back button in browser to come back page 1.

- then page 1 send request $.ajax.

- I want that when i click back button in browser, it comes back page 1 and uses old JSON that was received to show and don't send request.

 there're anyone who knows about this. Please help me!.

Thanks!

Comment: You can cache your response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12372670/3882178 and make a far future expiry-header!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much text it is you want to store.
but since it is json result I think its pretty much.
I haven't used this but you could save it on the disk and load it from there
Look into this : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js
You have to save it somewhere if you don't want to make the request again. 
filesystem, cookie, cache, session. somewhere else :)