# How to open a file from WebAPI where in server accepts specific Header

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, download

I am trying to download a document from a webAPI. The URL I am trying to bind to a link, but url also takes Accept header.

**How to pass in the Accept header along with the request?**

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax) link but am not able to figure out how to set Header when binding webAPI URL to a link in html. (I would prefer not to use File downloader for now).

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know you can't pass a header from a normal html link, this could be a duplicate of [Pass request headers in a jQuery AJAX GET call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call)