# How to Send a push notification through GCM using XHR (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, push-notification, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-messaging

This is my curl command to send notification through terminal. It works properly but how to send notification on button click(using XHR request)

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSyCjrU5SqotSg2ybDLK0dMusvY" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"f5xzshqcfDE2qiKGJu858nFhqGCuk0uuUC6vm\"]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a php script to serve the purpose and just make an XHR  request with client ,like javascript or any other of your choice.
Here is my php script I did it some months ago and it is working.

```
    <?php
    $message = "\": 3,\"title\": \"High score alert!\",\"\": true,\"custom_field\": { \"score\": 51,\"headlines\": \"And now for something completely different...\" }}";
    $apiKey = "Your Key";
    $registrationIDs = array("Registration id");
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    // Set POST variables
    $notify = array(
       "alert"=> "great match!",
      "title"=> "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" => "myicon",
      "badge"=>3,
      "vibrate"=>true,
    "notification"=>"message"
    );

    $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
    'data' => array( "payload"  => $notify,
    "notification"=>json_encode($notify)));
    $headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init(); // Open connection
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ));
    var_dump( $url );
    var_dump($headers);
    var_dump(json_encode( $fields ));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);   // Execute post
    if($result === false)
    die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response = json_decode($result);
    print_r($response);
    ?>
```

Comment: thanx for your answer but i don't want to use php.Is there any way to do this with javascript

Comment: is javascript suitable or you ?

Comment: yes i can also use ajax..... is there any way to do this with ajax,jquery @Asim Khan

Comment: Please read 
[this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call)