# Form submission with Sweetalert2 and Laravel: How?

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert2

I want to use Sweetalert2 to confirm wether you want to delete a record or not. If you press "DELETE" and there's an error, show another sweetalert popup. If there's no error, redirect to homepage.

All I did was prevent the default submission of the form and make an ajax request when "delete" is pressed (so `result.isConfirmed` is `true`). I've been trying to pass the CSRF token in `data` and `headers` too but I get this error all the time:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: bkF3gnRCrqiVjvKKLnP2kih90lYssXIINjIpLK8v is not defined
```

I'm not sure if that's doable and if so, how, but I would like to ask for some help. This is what I have so far:

```js
*..prevent default and first sweetalert popup..*
.then((result) => {
if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                        url:'{{ route("site.destroy", $record->id) }}',
                        headers: ('X-CSRF-Token', {{ csrf_token() }}),
                        error: ()=>{
                            Swal.fire(
                                'Something went wrong!',
                                'record was not deleted.',
                                'error')
                        }
*..end..*
```

Comment: The error says your JS is finding a big garbage string it doesn't expect.  Look at your code, where is such a string?  There's only one place - your CSRF token.  So what's funny about that? It is missing quotes!  But you've also got brackets around the headers, and a comma separating the key/value, a quick look at [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and a search for [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call) show that is incorrect.  `headers: {"X-CSRF-Token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"}`.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: If I use the code piece you sent, it throws `405` error instead, so I'm guessing it won't get the csrf token? I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it tho.

Comment: Did you check what 405 means?  It seems you have moved on to a new problem, you have no route set up for this request.  Check your browser devtools, you'll see a) if the request really happens; b) if the right header is included; c) the server response. If you have concerns about how you're sending CSRF (it looks fine to me), there are thousands of examples here on SO, copy one! :-)

Comment: I do have a route set-up for that request, since all I want to do is add Sweetalert2 inbetween the form submission and the record deletion.

Comment: I'm also using Laravel's "Route", so using "route("site.destroy", $record->id)" actually gives you the URL: `localhost:8000/destroy/0000` where 0000 is the $record->id provided. (0000 is not an actual id, just an example)

Comment: And what is the route you have set up, in `web.php`? What does `php artisan route:list` show?

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the solution,

- you have syntax error (try to use header as key-value pair).
- Try this way.

**JavaScript code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{{ route("site.destroy", $record->id) }}',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    error: () => {
        Swal.fire(
            'Something went wrong!',
            'record was not deleted.',
            'error'
        );
    }
});
```

*Hope you will fix the issue :)*

Comment: Why do you think this is necessary?  Passing CSRF as a header is perfectly fine, it is even in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: you are correct brother. If this is not the issue we can try to access csrf token using key-value pair. not as a tuple. I will edit my answer. Thanks.